# Question about the syntax and translation of Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have written code as below

```
datatype
  Sign=positive  ("+"  100)
  |negative ("-" 100)



typedecl sigma

type_synonym
  signed_msg="Sign\<times>  msg"

type_synonym 
  node=" sigma \<times> nat"

type_synonym
  strand_space="sigma   => signed_msg  list "
consts
  Sigma_set::"sigma set" ("\<Sigma>")

consts
  SP::"strand_space"

definition 
  Domain::"node set" where
  "Domain == {(n1,i). n1 \<in>  \<Sigma>  \<and> i < length (SP n1)}"

definition strand::"node => sigma" where
  "strand n==fst n"

definition index ::"node => nat" where
  "index n == snd n"

definition node_sign ::"node => Sign" where
   "node_sign n ==fst (nth (SP(fst(n))) (snd(n)) )"



definition  node_term ::"node\<Rightarrow>msg" where
  "node_term n==  snd (nth (SP(fst(n))) (snd(n)) )"

definition
  casual1 :: "( node × node ) set " where
  "casual1 == { (n1,n2) . n1 ∈  Domain ∧ n2 ∈  Domain ∧
  node_sign n1= +  ∧
  node_sign n2= -  ∧ 
  node_term n1= node_term n2  ∧  
  strand n1 ≠ strand n2    
  } "
syntax
  "_casual1"::" node ⇒ node ⇒ bool" (infix "\<rightarrow>" 100)
translations
  "n1 → n2 "=="(n1 ,n2) ∈ casual1"
```

But Isabelle tells me that "Error in syntax translation rule: rhs contains extra variables ("_casual1" n1 n2) ↝ ("<^const>Set.member" ("_tuple" n1 ("_tuple_arg" n2)) casual1)". Because I don't understand the mechanism of translations well, can not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a translation that depends on a constant you've defined, you need to put the `CONST` keyword before it:

```
syntax
  "_casual1"::" node ⇒ node ⇒ bool" (infix "\<rightarrow>" 100)
translations
  "n1 → n2 "=="(n1 ,n2) ∈ CONST casual1"
```

This tells Isabelle to search for a constant named `casual1`, so it will find your earlier definition

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solves my problem.  I have another question that it seems that Isabelle2021 remove the  constdefs keyword, how can i use other form to express the constdefs clause, like definition or others.